# Memoization doesn't seem to be working as intended

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

The problem I am trying to solve is:

```
Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

Example:

Input:
[
  [1,3,1],
  [1,5,1],
  [4,2,1]
]
Output: 7
Explanation: Because the path 1→3→1→1→1 minimizes the sum
```

So, this is the recursive implementation that I can up with:

```
class Solution {
    public int minPathSum(int[][] grid) {
        int[][] memo = new int[grid.length][grid[0].length];
       return minPathSum(grid, 0, 0, 0, memo);
    }

    public int minPathSum(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int sum, int[][] memo) {
        if(i == grid.length-1 && j == grid[0].length-1) {
            return sum+grid[i][j];
        }
        else if(i>=grid.length || j >= grid[0].length) {
            return 10000;
        }
        else {

            return Math.min(minPathSum(grid,i+1,j,sum+grid[i][j], memo), minPathSum(grid,i,j+1,sum+grid[i][j], memo));

        }
    }
}
```

Followed By the memoized algorithm:

```
class Solution {
    public int minPathSum(int[][] grid) {
        int[][] memo = new int[grid.length][grid[0].length];
       return minPathSum(grid, 0, 0, 0, memo);
    }

    public int minPathSum(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int sum, int[][] memo) {
        if(i == grid.length-1 && j == grid[0].length-1) {
            return sum+grid[i][j];
        }
        else if(i>=grid.length || j >= grid[0].length) {
            return 10000;
        }
        else {
            if(memo[i][j] == 0)
            memo[i][j] = Math.min(minPathSum(grid,i+1,j,sum+grid[i][j], memo), minPathSum(grid,i,j+1,sum+grid[i][j], memo));
            return memo[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

However, my memoized algorithm fails for the case of [[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]], whose expected output is 7. My inefficent recursive algorithm returns 7. However, my memoized algorithm returns the wrong answer of 9. I can't seem to find out why this is. I have always done memoization like this and it's strange that it returns the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the sum variable in your method at all. Your input is:

```
[
  [1,3,1],
  [1,5,1],
  [4,2,1]
]
```

and initially your memo is,

```
[
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
]
```

The very first cell in memo which will get calculated is (2,2) and it will have a total of 9 because it calculates the answer of the path (0,0)->(1,0)->(2,0)->(2,1) and then finally (2,2). But this is wrong since it should only hold the value which represents the minimum answer for that subgrid.

Try using the memo like so,

```
public int minPathSum(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int[][] memo) {
        if(i == grid.length-1 && j == grid[0].length-1) {
            memo[i][j] = grid[i][j];
            return grid[i][j];
        }
        else if(i>=grid.length || j >= grid[0].length) {
            return 10000;
        }
        else {
            int val = grid[i][j]+Math.min(minPathSum(grid,i+1,j, memo), minPathSum(grid,i,j+1, memo));
            if(memo[i][j] > val || memo[i][j] == 0){
                memo[i][j] = val;
            }
            for(int k = 0;k<memo.length;k++){
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(memo[k]));
            }
            System.out.println("i:"+i+" j:"+j);
            return memo[i][j];
        }
    }
```

A sample run gives me the following output:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 3, 1]
i:2 j:1
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[7, 3, 1]
i:2 j:0
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[7, 3, 1]
i:2 j:1
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:1 j:2
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:1 j:1
[0, 0, 0]
[8, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:1 j:0
[0, 0, 0]
[8, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:2 j:1
[0, 0, 0]
[8, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:1 j:2
[0, 0, 0]
[8, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:1 j:1
[0, 0, 0]
[8, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:1 j:2
[0, 0, 3]
[8, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:0 j:2
[0, 6, 3]
[8, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:0 j:1
[7, 6, 3]
[8, 7, 2]
[7, 3, 1]
i:0 j:0
7
```

Every cell holds the answer for the subgrid of which the cell is the topmost and leftmost element. Later, the cell is updated is it has not been updated initially (i.e cellvalue == 0) OR if the newly found solution is lesser than what is present (i.e if cellvalue>new answer)

Comment: if(memo[i][j] > val part is not necessary

Comment: @juvian, oh yes actually ... thanks a lot for pointing it out! :)